# Can I get a pilot's license if my driver's license has been suspended?

Tags: faa-regulations

My driver's license is suspended because I got a bunch of tickets. It was the first time and I've paid the tickets. Can I still go for a private pilot's license?

Answer (score 1):

The FAA has a guide on applying for a medical/student license

https://medxpress.faa.gov/MedXpress/Content/Docs/MedXPressUsersGuide.pdf

Near the end, pages 30-33. They ask for consent to review your National Driver Register.  Read those pages, see if any of it applies to you.

Comment: Can you include some of the relevant content so that those of us who hate clicking links can view it?

Comment: Unable. Cannot copy the PDF document.

Comment: Fair enough.   I should have clicked on the link and observed that!

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question? The MedXpress instructions are just instructions for filling out the application, they don't say anything about what may be disqualifying or not.

Comment: Read the box at the bottom of Block 18, and 20, on page 33, where it inquires about driving history. I don't know how much you have had to screw up driving to be disqualified for flying - but you are required to consent to them looking into it.  There's also this for more info https://www.faa.gov/news/updates/?newsId=87125   I was not able to locate anything with this search  https://www.faa.gov/search/?q=driving+record+disqualification  As far as I know, applications go to FAA's OK City office for review for anything that might be questionable.

Comment: More details  18.v. History of Arrest(s), Conviction(s), and/or Administrative Action(s).
Arrest(s), conviction(s) and/or administrative action(s) affecting driving privileges may raise questions about the applicant's fitness for certification and may be cause for disqualification. A single driving while intoxicated (DWI) arrest, conviction and/or administrative action usually is not cause for denial provided there are no other instances or indications of substance dependence or abuse. See Substances of
Dependence/Abuse.

Comment: From here  2018 GUIDE FOR AVIATION MEDICAL EXAMINERS 
 https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/guide.pdf  Also discussed is the Sport Pilot license, with has limitations on what can be flown and where.  Ok for a start to flying. Can't do everything can be done with a Private Pilot License - that discussion can be left to another question.  Bottom line: keep your driving record clean to avoid giving the FAA any reasons to 
 go after your license.